# How to git pull origin with github Actions workflow

Tags: github, devops, github-actions

I'm new to github actions workflow

I have a self-hosted runner and I have cloned a
repo named `xxx`

I want to do `git pull origin branchYY` in the actions workflow so that the local repo is up to date with the remote branch 'branchYY' of xxx repo

I tried the following workflow:

```
name: Pull origin branchYY
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - branchYY
jobs:
  auto-pull:
    name: PullOriginBranchYY
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - run: |
        git config user.name johnn
        git config user.email soemthing@mail.com
        git config github.token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        git pull origin branchYY
      working-directory: /home/user/repos/xxx
```

But the local runner is prompting for:

> Username for 'https://github.com':

I dont get why its not authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout) you should configure token using proper argument.
I suggest you use ssh to clone

Answer (score 0):

Within a GitHub Actions workflow, you can use the [RFC 7617](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617) HTTP Basic Access Authentication syntax of `username:password` over HTTPS like so:

```
remote_repo="https://${GITHUB_ACTOR}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}.git"
git pull "$remote_repo" branchYY
```

The variables `$GITHUB_ACTOR`, `$GITHUB_TOKEN`, and `$GITHUB_REPOSITORY` are [Default GitHub Actions Environment Variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables).

HTTPS will [encrypt conversations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) with the Microsoft Servers and the `$GITHUB_TOKEN` won't be printed out.

There are several discussions (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493073/using-a-github-fine-grained-token-with-git-pull-over-https) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed/68781050#68781050)) that passing the token to the URL is not very secure, which are valid. However, these are about running the command from the terminal, not within a GitHub Actions workflow.

To date, within a workflow, this seems to work well.