# Message "Support for password authentication was removed."

Tags: git, github, github-api, git-pull, personal-access-token

I got this error on my console when I tried to use `git pull`:

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
> remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
> fatal: Authentication failed for ...

It's very weird, because I just followed the documentation and created a token two weeks ago on GitHub. The token expires on Tue, Oct 26, 2021. Why has this been removed today?

Comment: Sometimes it uses ssh-askpass tool from SSH_ASKPASS env variable and stores the password in wallet. To overcome this either change/remove the values in wallet or
`unset SSH_ASKPASS`

Answer (score 2080):

From 2021-08-13, GitHub is no longer accepting account passwords when authenticating Git operations. You need to add a **PAT (Personal Access Token)** instead, and you can follow the below method to add a PAT on your system.

> ### Create Personal Access Token on GitHub
>
> From your GitHub account, go to **Settings** → **Developer Settings** → **Personal Access Token** → **Tokens (classic)** → **Generate New Token** (Give your password) → **Fillup the form** → click **Generate token** → **Copy the generated Token**, it will be something like `ghp_sFhFsSHhTzMDreGRLjmks4Tzuzgthdvfsrta`

Now follow the below method based on your machine:

> ### For Windows OS [⤴](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0)
>
> Go to **Credential Manager** from **Control Panel** → **Windows Credentials** → find `git:https://github.com` → **Edit** → On Password replace with with your **GitHub Personal Access Token** → You are Done
>
> If you don’t find `git:https://github.com` → Click on **Add a generic credential** → Internet address will be `git:https://github.com` and you need to type in your username and password will be your **GitHub Personal Access Token** → Click Ok and you are done

---

> ### For macOS [⤴](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)
>
> Click on the Spotlight icon (magnifying glass) on the right side of the menu bar. Type **Keychain access** then press the Enter key to launch the app → In Keychain Access, search for `github.com` → Find the **internet password** entry for `github.com` → Edit or delete the entry accordingly → You are done

---

> ### For a Linux-based OS [⤴](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache)
>
> For Linux, you need to configure the local GIT client with a username
> and email address,
>
> ```
> $ git config --global user.name "your_github_username"
> $ git config --global user.email "your_github_email"
> $ git config -l
> ```
>
> Once GIT is configured, we can begin using it to access GitHub.
> Example:
>
> ```
> $ git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
> > Cloning into `YOUR-REPOSITORY`...
> Username: <type your username>
> Password: <type your password or personal access token (GitHub)
> ```
>
> Now cache the given record in your computer to remembers the token:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global credential.helper cache
> ```
>
> If needed, anytime you can delete the cache record by:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global --unset credential.helper
> $ git config --system --unset credential.helper
> ```
>
> Now try to pull with `-v` to verify
>
> ```
> $ git pull -v
> ```

> **Linux/Debian**
> (Clone as follows):
>
> ```
> git clone https://<tokenhere>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
> ```

---

> ### For PhpStorm
>
> If you are using PhpStorm, go to menu **Git** → **pull** and select authentication via **Personal Access Token**. Enter your `PAT` it will allow you to pull/push the changes.

Comment: Be sure to save the token on some local file or in some cloud.Upvoted.

Comment: Given that the OP states they already created a token two weeks ago, this doesn't address the actual problem.

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke Save it in a password manager, with all the security that comes around with that. Not in some random unprotected file.

Comment: Ummmm, it isn't asking for a token when I clone my repo, how should I proceed then?

Comment: @Prhyme I think you can clone public repo without password, but not private repo

Comment: Same experience as @Prhyme. I am not able to get git to prompt me for username  and password, even trying to clone private repos, push to repos, etc. When I go to push to a repo, it continues to give the "Support for password authentication was removed" message, without prompting for anything.

Comment: You definitely *do not* want to delete your GitHub password from macOS's Keychain, the "internet password" entry is the saved password from Safari.

Comment: In Mac, I open keychain and find that github item, but how could I change the password with token?

Comment: @CHUCKZHB This can help https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

Comment: command `git config --global credential.helper store` is for who want to permanent store their `token`. The token will be store in your disk. This method is the easiest but not safe at all.

Comment: Notice on mac: Direct search&delete the github key cannot work on my mac. Please try to select Local items on the sidebar then do the search&delete, this would be fine

Comment: Does not answer the question. See the answer from @ßãlãjî below

Comment: in macOS, delete github item in key chain not work. but  use `For Linux based OS` method `unset credential.helper` work.

Comment: in macOS, delete github item in key chain not work. but  use `For Linux based OS` method `unset credential.helper` work.

Comment: It didn't work for me on Ubuntu. I tried to pull a branch but it kept showing the same error.

Comment: That was awesome - would have taken me a while to get that old one replaced in OS X. Thanks!

Comment: What if several people use the same Windows account to push data under different github profiles?

Comment: @Yola you can use the same Windows account to push data under different github profiles

Comment: For mac first time, when you are prompted for a password when you pushing the code to your repo, enter the access token, It will add the token in the keychain and it won't prompt again.

Comment: Wouldn't the `git config` option cause problems if you use Github **and** Gitlab? Would you have to change those every time you pushed to one or the other? Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: @jrh this is for Github, you need to setup the PAT one time not every time

Comment: @sta right, but then wouldn't your commit email / username show as whatever@users.github.com on Gitlab?

Comment: @jrh you can keep your email addresses private on your commits, [check this](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address)

Comment: @sta Right, Github uses a different email address than [Gitlab](https://forum.kicad.info/t/why-use-a-real-email-address-in-git/24644) for that. If I set my user preferences in Git to one site, it will break the other one.

Comment: but it keep asking the username & password eventough i already set it the credential under control panel (windows).... what is missing for this matter?

Comment: I have a breaking bug in my Keychain access so I used the Linux terminal commands instead, it worked perfectly on my Mac OS.

Comment: Might be obvious but you need to check the "repo" checkbox when creating the token. I found it a little misleading that "read and write code to repo" is not a sub-option of the main "repo" checkbox.

Comment: username command not found when typed: 
```Username for 'https://github.com' : username```

Comment: I updated it with a token and github pages (jekyll) keeps on asking me for login and password whenI deploy new branch...

Comment: I don't find any "Developer Settings" in "Settings" in my Github Account

Comment: In case people are struggling to find the Developer Settings tab -> https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: Also when generating personal token, remember to check all the necessary permission on github or access might get denied.

Comment: why do I get username not found when I do the token part on linux?

Comment: what exactly means "edit or delete accordingly"? which one of thousands github entries I should edit? What fields to edit?

Comment: When I try enter password I got same error ?

Comment: Save the key in notes files realy handy, but that configuration command does the job for not asking for password again and again

Comment: @ßãlãjî answer is better I think!. For mac it will repo based control rather.

Comment: why not use password authentication? forcing users to opt from this kind of procedure

Comment: @ajgo password authentication is no longer available for Github, use Personal Access Token instead

Comment: @sta - yes, but why they force to use that?

Comment: @ajgo it's a high security issue

Comment: @sta - so its disappointing that their authentication for passwords is that vulnerable

Comment: What does this mean? "Find the internet password entry for github.com " I already put in my GitHub password and got the authentication message! ??

Comment: @user2568374 that line is based on Github official documentation, here  https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

Comment: Not working for Ubuntu

Comment: This is, not surprisingly, [plagiarised on Medium](https://litoarias.medium.com/token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations-5fdd8a6f6e7c) (wholesale copy-pasted). This is listed together with two other pages in the reference section, but that doesn't make it less plagiarised. It also plagiarises those two other pages (wholesale copy-paste).

Comment: my cmder is still asking me for my username and password after doing the above steps on windows

Comment: It looks like `git config --global credential.helper cache` cannot save the key between boots?

Comment: you should add that the sudo command is required for the linux commands

Comment: In the above Personal Access Token, just remember to give Read / Write permission to all your repositories and all repositories / number of days and just public repository / All and you would need to give access manually from respective drop after expanding. You could compare after reading below that how many of your repositories and what permissions are given. Cheers.

Comment: For WSL users see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925964/how-to-use-git-credential-store-on-wsl-ubuntu-on-windows).

Comment: this helps me and save my time thanks for detail and proper explaination .

Answer (score 590):

### If you're using macOS, just simply follow these steps:

1. Go to [this link](https://github.com/settings/tokens):   (Profile -> settings -> developers setting -> personal access tokens). (don't go to repository setting; it's your profile setting)
2. Generate a new token and copy-paste it somewhere safely.
3. Now search for an app in your Mac, named `Keychain Access`.
4. Search for `github.com` (if there are multiple GitHub logins then choose `Kind: Internet password`), double-click it.
5. Click on show password, then enter your Mac's password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Password should be visible by now. Now, just paste the token you generated in step 2 and click <kbd>Save changes</kbd>.

And that's it. Enjoy!

### If you're using Windows:

1. Follow steps 1 and 2 as above.
2. Search for an application in your Windows OS, named *Credential Manager* → then *Windows Credentials*.
3. Search for `github.com` and *edit* the password with the `token` you have generated on GitHub.
   Now enjoy!

### Developer's hack (shortcode):

```
git remote set-url origin https://<githubtoken>@github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>.git
```

While cloning:

```
git clone https://<username>:<githubtoken>@github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>.git
```

It will work on every OS (Mac, Windows, or Linux).

Cons: You have to remember or should need to do to each repository in your local. So I'll prefer everyone to use above mentioned steps.

### NOTE:

For those who don't have this entry: it could be made. one way to do it is- to clone a project. then it will ask for your username and password. instead of password give it the token and then the entry would be made.

Comment: I found that on Windows, it was necessary to *delete* the existing credential in the credential manager. Then, the next time I tried to do a `git push`, it prompted for the Personal Access Token. Simply resetting the existing credential did not work.

Comment: This option worked for me. I was struggling to push to an existing repository and after changing the password with the key, it works.

Comment: For me, credential manager didn't update. I had to remove the entry. on the next pull a popup appeared asking for PAT, I entered it and it was saved anew.

Comment: The developer hack worked good for me (I go between Github, Gitlab, and multiple accounts on each site) but it seems to me that this is a *major security downgrade* from just typing in a password, each one of these repos can push directly to Github without asking for a password at all; how is this safer?

Comment: If you use Firefox, probably there is no github.com password in Keychain. In this case just log in to github.com with Safari

Comment: For those who does not have this entry: it should be made . one way to do it is to clone a project. then it will ask for your username and password. instead of password give it the token and then the entry would be made.

Comment: That didn't work for me. http://rodmclaughlin.com/difficulties-with-github-s-new-security-system

Comment: using the generated token as github password on terminal screen.

Comment: @DarkNeuron 1. In Keychain Access, make sure you're viewing 'All Items' i.e. it shouldn't be set to certificate, keys, otherwise you won't see it. 2. The 'developer's hack' way created the entry and added the token, so no other work was needed by me

Comment: Search for github.com (if there are multiple GitHub logins then choose Kind: Internet password), double-click it. 

this doesn't ever show up

Comment: If you don't have `github.com` in Keychain, simply `push` a commit to github in your command line. It will ask for your username and password. Enter your username, and use the personal access token you just created as your password.

Comment: The developer hack of simply doing git remote set-url origin worked perfectly for me. You can also confirm if the change made it through gits config by looking at the "remote.origin.url=" field when you do git config --list

Comment: I have tried both my Mac password and the Github password in keychain and neither work.

Comment: doesn't work for sourcetree

Answer (score 385):

Use *My Account* → *Settings* → *Developer settings* → *Personal access tokens* → *Generate new token*.

```
git remote set-url origin https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>
```

Comment: Note that this seems to require running this command in each repo for that repo to be reset with the new credentials. Hopefully there is a global solution.

Comment: This one perfectly worked for me. The above one with maximum vote didn't work.

Comment: But with a token anybody with this token can push to your repo. In a public computer how would you keep the password protection?

Comment: Thanks! Using token as password not work, but adding this work awesome

Comment: This is very insecure, not only does it allow anyone on the local system with read access to the local repo control over that repo, `git remote -v` simply discloses the key giving the attacker account wide access to your GitHub account.

Comment: @ßãlãjî OS key managers and browsers take grate pains to secure credentials. Normal git workflow do not expose passwords or ssh private keys to other users with read access to a repo. The above advice does. It allows anyone with read access to a copy of a local repo, including for example a shared work or school filesystem, to see the user's clear text Personal Access Token. This extends to archived copies as well, such as source tarballs that retain the `.git` directory.

Comment: If you are working on someone else's repo, replace the <username> with their own (the one found at the URL, right after "https://github.com/" and before the following "/")

Comment: It still asks for a password even with the token in the url:
Password for 'https://<token>@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.

Comment: this works for me if i don't put in the <username>,
so git clone https://<token>@github.com/<repo>

Comment: The only way it works for me (mac os) is this command, but I need to generate a new token for each repo. when reusing the same token with different repos i get prompted to use password. what a mess

Comment: fatal: No such remote 'origin'

Comment: @Xu shan your URL must be a wrong Check correctly  once again and submit

Comment: doesn't work for me, still asks for password

Answer (score 226):

### For Linux these simple steps can solve your problem

1. If your Git password is cached in *credential.helper*, then unset it:

   ```
   git config --local --unset credential.helper
   ```

   Or, If you have set your credentials globally, then:

   ```
   git config --global --unset credential.helper
   ```
2. Now go to your GitHub *Account settings*

   [image]
3. Click *Developer Settings*

   [image]
4. Select *Personal Access*

   [image]
5. Generate a token with the given permissions, e.g.,

   [image]
6. Now `git pull` inside your Git repository
7. Provide a username and the generated token as a password

[image]

That is a straightforward solution step by step.

### PS: If you are annoyed by Git asking for username/token again and again, follow these three simple steps

- Run `nano ~/.git-credentials`. Remove the GitHub line and save it.
- `git config --global credential.helper store`

  Risky as physically the token is saved in file `~/.git-credentials`
- Run `git pull` and provide the username and password only once

It will not ask for the username and access token again and again now!

Comment: Those are a *lot* of permissions. What are you using that token for?

Comment: It all depends on the use case you want to use that token for.  So select those permissions according to your use case.

Comment: It only worked when I followed this.

Comment: Is there a way to save it to a custom location? Perhaps it can help reduce the risk?

Comment: Do NOT do that with permissions.

Comment: Thanks a LOT <3 your command prompt screenshot helped and worked like charm. I simply used the token as password even in SmartGit.

Comment: This method did work, thank you. To be sure, if we do not want the token saved in plain text currently, the only solution is to either memorize the ssh token or go to github whenever we want to push a change?

Comment: I just did Regenerate token, and then follow step 6-7

Comment: @LeandroBardelli can you explain why they should not follow that permission?

Comment: @AdrianGaileSingh permissions should be granted in "NONE to specifics" not in "ALL but specifics". Do not give permissions that you wont need never. even more if the process is automated.

Answer (score 203):

**For Windows OS,**

GitHub has made changes in password authentication. If you are trying to access Git by username and password then it does not allow you. So use a **personal access token** instead of a password to access Git everywhere.

Here are the steps to generate **personal access tokens**.

Click here for Token - https://github.com/settings/tokens

Step 1 - Open GitHub and log in with your credentials.

Step 2 - Click on the **Setting** menu.

Step 3 - From the **Setting** menu click on **Developer Settings**

Step 4 - From the **Developer Settings** menu, click on **Personal access token**

Step 5 - From the **Personal access token**, click on the **Generate new Token** button.

Step 6 - Now fill up required details like **Note, Expiration, Select scopes**. And then click on the **Generate Token** button.

Step 7 - After that, a new token has been generated. Copy that generated token and use this token to access Git with username and token.

If you are using the Windows operating system then please follow the below step.

Open **Control Panel** → **User Accounts** →  **Manage your credentials** → **Windows Credentials**.

It will show all generic credentials. Find your GitHub URL and click on that. Now click on the **edit** button. And then add the **personal access token** generated from **GitHub** into the password field. And click on the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

Now you can access Git.

If you are accessing Git in Android Studio, if asked for a password then add the GitHub **personal access token** instead of your password everywhere.

Answer (score 106):

This message means that you're using a password instead of a personal access token to access GitHub over HTTPS, and that's no longer allowed.  GitHub has disabled password authentication because it's common for people to accidentally leak their passwords, and while a personal access token can be restricted to limit the damage, a password cannot.

If you haven't explicitly entered your password at a prompt, then it's likely you have a credential manager which is saving your password and sending it without prompting you.

You can follow the directions for clearing your credential manager [listed in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials):

```
$ echo url=https://account@github.com | git credential reject
```

You should use this same URL, but replace `account` with your own username (e.g., in my case, it would look like `echo url=https://bk2204@github.com`).

Then, the next time you try to push or pull, Git will prompt you for a username and password.  For the username, enter your GitHub username, and for the password, generate a new personal access token [on the appropriate settings page](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and paste it into the password field.  If you're working from the command line, you may not see any indication that the password was successfully pasted; this is normal, so just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> afterwards.

That will save the personal access token in your credential manager for the next time, assuming you have one set up.  If you're not sure if you have one set up, run `git config credential.helper` and see if it outputs anything.

If you don't have one set up, you should add one so that you don't have to memorize your token.  Run one of the following commands, depending on operating system:

- `git config --global credential.helper manager` on Windows;
- `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain` on macOS;
- `git config --global credential.helper libsecret` on Linux (if available); or
- `git config --global credential.helper store` on Linux if `libsecret` isn't available.

Then you can try the push or pull again until you're no longer prompted.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just tested `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain` and `git config --global credential.helper` but nothing is happening in my console, so I will try the first solution. Just one question, what is the `url=https://account@github.com`? The link of my repot or my github?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776300/github-change-from-password-to-person-access-token-without-re-cloning-the-repo/68776344#68776344 to change the password on a mac

Comment: The technique I've mentioned above will clear the password on any system so Git will prompt for it again.  That's why we documented it in the FAQ, because the directions are different for each individual OS and credential helper and it's too hard to write a single answer that applies to all systems when it involves the GUI.

Comment: `echo url=https://account@github.com | git credential reject` was just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: This was the way to fix things, thanks! Apparently I had done everything right according to the numberous reminders, but nowhere did it actually say *how to start using the tokens*...

Comment: Thanks buddy. I knew it already but kept on forgetting it as I don't put code on github generally.

Comment: Still getting `remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.`

Answer (score 68):

Simplest solution (May 2022):

1. Create a new token at *[Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens)*
2. Copy token (Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, macOS: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, or click copy icon)
3. Try to push your local repository: `git push`
4. Enter your GitHub user name
5. Paste the token as your password

Comment: I cannot verify that this _all_ that is needed, but I it very well might. You see, based on answers above I put the PAT into the Keychain Access (Mac) and then I pasted the PAT for password on the command line when prompted during my 'git clone' command. Maybe I didn't need to put PAT in Keychain Access. I can say that if I do another clone I am _not_ prompted for auth. _If_ this answer is _all_ one needs to do then this is the best answer.

Answer (score 43):

Generate an access token in GitHub from *Settings* → *Developer settings*.

If you have cloned your repository in the past and made it as *origin*, then you can change the authentication so,

```
git remote set-url origin https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
```

If you are going to clone repository after 13 August 2021, then you can use the normal clone command and set the generated access token in the password field.

Comment: And it should be "<repo>.git".

Comment: If you're like me and have years worth of git repos that you used password based auth on. I have made this:

`find . -type f -path '*/.git/*' -name 'config' -exec sed -i 's%https://github.com/%git@github.com:%g' {} \;`

It will recursively search in the `.git` folder for any file called config and find and replace the https URL with the git@github one. I'd recommend only doing this on simple repos where you know you have plain vanilla remotes. I haven't tested how it will work on different setups. YMMV!

Comment: I tried removing the username and it worked:
 git remote set-url origin https://<token>@github.com/<repo>.git

Answer (score 34):

For **Ubuntu**, use the following steps

- At https://github.com/settings/tokens, go and generate a token.
- `git push`
- `username: user_github_username`
- `password: add_generated_token` instead of the password.

Answer (score 24):

#### A one-command simple solution to solve it

*If your computer has no SSH key added to the GitHub account, I add information for you to do it at the end of the answer. You should do it first.*

After push failed, then do this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:{user_id}/{project_name}.git
```

And push again. Then it works.

Let me show my case in the following. 
(And I will guide you on how to do your case.)

At the first, when I add, commit, and push, then I meet this issue:

[image]

And then, my current Git log is the following.

[image]

In the final, this is my way to solve the issue.

[image]

In my case,

1. **{project_name}** <-> open-idea-pool
2. **{user_id}** <-> milochen0418 is the
3. **{branch_name}** <-> master

(your *branch_name* maybe is *main*, but not *master*)

When I push failed, the only thing I need is this one command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:{user_id}/{project_name}.git
```

Then I push it again by:

```
git push -u origin {branch_name}
```

For the example of my case,

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:milochen0418/open-idea-pool.git
git push -u origin master
```

It works.

--
By the way, this is the process of creating an SSH key to GitHub account.

You can refer to these two links to do it. The information here supports Mac, Windows, and Linux.

1. *[Issue on adding SSH key to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612504/issue-on-adding-ssh-key-to-github/35612800#35612800)*
2. *[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)*

Furthermore, if you want to clone a new project, you can do the following command:

```
git clone git@github.com:{user_id}/{project_name}.git
```

Comment: I bet this works only because you have an SSH key added to the github account.

Comment: Maybe add the process of creating an SSH key to the answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will add some simple processes of creating an SSH key tomorrow. 
GitHub official doc also introduces how to do it, but that's is too complicated for junior people.

Comment: I've done to add the process of creating an SSH key to github account by refer two excellent links.

Comment: Advisable to use `ssh` instead of using `username/password(token)` approach. Good answer. Instead of `https://github.com/<repo_url>` use `git@github.com:<repo_url>`

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68784033/edit) (it covers terminal sessions as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

You can force your machine to just use SSH instead of HTTPS:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Comment: this is actually the easiest solution; i wonder if there is no caveats in this

Comment: `SSH` is even safer than `HTTPS` for `authentication` because you'll never need to send your secret over the internet. The other part (git server in this case) only knows your `public key` and you just need to keep safe your `private key` in your machine. That's why `strong authentication` use such approach. You could also protect your private key with something like `chmod 400 your_key`. Where 4 is the permission for you to read only your key without the risk of modifying it and 0 permissions on your secret for any user in your group and 0 for the rest of the world as well.

Comment: I had the same symptoms as OP, and this answer solved it for me, i.e opening the Git config file and replace the HTTPS address with the SSH one.

Comment: This had to be the answer with the most votes...

Answer (score 15):

For Mac, go and create your token. You can only see it once. Copy it and store it securely.

Open up Terminal and run: `gh auth login`

*gh can be installed using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))

Answer the questions. Make sure you pick HTTPS when asked.

[image: Terminal prompt]

Answer (score 15):

If you're using [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) and do not find the github.com entry in the KeyChain access:

- Try to do a Git action
- It'll ask for the user name
- Enter your GitHub user name
- Generate a new key from *[Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens)*
- In the password field, enter this newly generated token value
- Now you can see a new entry of github.com inside KeyChain Access → *login*

Answer (score 12):

Go to *Settings* → *Developer settings* → generate a new token if it does not exist.

Or copy the token if it exists.

[image]

Then set the token:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git/
```

Answer (score 12):

First create the token on GitHub:

1. Click on the profile picture and in the menu select **Settings**
2. Select **Developer Settings** in the left menu at the bottom
3. Select **Personal Access tokens** in the left menu (third option)
4. Select **Generate new token** and follow the next steps.

If you have not installed GitHub CLI, you would not find it in your keychain Access. Therefore you should install it first.

1. Install GitHub CLI for macOS

   ```
   brew install gh
   ```

   For Windows:

   ```
   winget install gh
   scoop install gh
   choco install gh
   ```
2. On the command line, enter `gh auth login`, follow the prompts, and provide the following answers

   *? What account do you want to log into?* **GitHub.com**

   *? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations?* **HTTPS**

   *? Authenticate Git with your GitHub credentials?* **Yes**

   *? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI?* Paste an authentication token
3. Paste the token you created on GitHub and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

**Generating a GitHub personal access token (PAT)**

1. Log in to your GitHub account and open *Settings* → *Developer Settings*
   Personal Access Tokens.
2. Click on `Generate New Token`.

> Do not forget to copy and the token after generation. It is accessible only once.

**Windows**

1. Open *Control Panel* → *User Accounts* → *Credential Manager*.
2. Now, look for `git:https://github.com`.
3. Click on *Edit*.
4. Replace the password with the GitHub Personal Access Token.

**MAC**

1. Click on Spotlight Icon and search for `Keychain Access`.
2. Inside Keychain Access, search for *github.com*.
3. Now, look for the internet password entry for github.com.
4. Update the entry.

Comment: I found that on Windows, it was necessary to _delete_ the existing credential in the credential manager. Then, the next time I tried to do a `git push`, it prompted for the Personal Access Token. Simply resetting the existing credential did not work.

Answer (score 9):

#### Mac users -- a simple solution.

Set up the personal access token in GitHub:

*Settings* → *Developer Settings* → *Personal access token*

Open *Keychain* → type "GitHub"

Change the password to the personal access token.

Try commit/pushing.

Select "Always allow" and business is as usual.

Answer (score 9):

I was using `git pull` on Linux with a password before.

If that is the case, the only thing you need to do is use **token** in place of **password**.

Generate an access token by going to *[Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens)*.

Here is example of `git pull`

```
git pull

Username for 'https://github.com': gitusername
Password for 'https://yourusername@github.com': //Then enter generated token
```

Comment: In my case after doing "git pull", just do "git pull" a second time and you should get prompted for the username and password automatically.  It shouldn't require you go to delete your password in the OS settings.

Answer (score 8):

To those using **[Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements)** with an *existing repository* you must update your repository URL like so
`https://<your_token>@github.com/username/repo.git`

This was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68780819/when-i-try-to-pull-or-push-in-github-i-am-getting-an-error-message-please-use/68784631#68784631).

Comment: git clone https://GIT_USER_NAME:<your_token>@github.com/username/repo.git

Answer (score 7):

If you want to clone for the first time:

```
git clone https://<repository_owner>:<personal_access_token>@github.com/<repository_owner>/<repo>.git
```

Answer (score 6):

**It worked!**

After getting the token key as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781050/14619383):

> **Create Personal Access Token on GitHub From your GitHub account**
>
> go to Settings => Developer Settings => Personal Access Token => Generate
> New Token (Give your password) => Fillup the form => click Generate
> token => Copy the generated Token (it will be something like
> `ghp_sFhFsSHhTzMDreGRLjmks4Tzuzgthdvfsrta`)

use the following in your terminal:

```
git clone https://your_username:your_github_token@github.com/username/private-repo.git
```

Answer (score 4):

In Linux, you can generate a new access token in GitHub and directly replace it in place of the password in the `~.git-credentials` file.

The password section starts with `:` and ends with `@`.

Answer (score 4):

**A quick solution for Windows users**

Open [Credential Manager](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/what-is-windows-credential-manager) and just remove the already-saved credentials for Git: https://github.com.

[image]

After this step, run the command again for pull/push in the terminal. GitHub will ask to log in with your default browser automatically (**make sure you are logged in with GitHub in the default browser**).

[image]

After successful login, we got this message:

[image]

For more help related to this, you can also watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9B4q1cfqgs&lc=UgzeX0BzD6jh91SoBcJ4AaABAg).

Answer (score 4):

> Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.

### Solution

1. [Create a GitHub personal access token (PAT)](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and copy it.
2. For macOS, add it to KeyChain Access under GitHub.

   Spotlight Search → type *KeyChain* → select *KeyChain Access* → search for github.com → paste your [PAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_access_token)

   [image: Put your PAT in the Show password field]

   For Windows, add the PAT to Windows credentials for your user.

   Search → type *Credential Manager* → *Add your PAT to github.com*

   [image]
3. *If the repository is part of an organization*, you will also need to *sign in* to that organization with your personal access token so that the organization will recognize it. If you're already signed in, sign out first.
4. `git clone` as usual :-)

Answer (score 4):

After getting the token key, you can just skip all steps and go with this:

```
git clone https://your_username:your_github_token@github.com/username/private-repo.git
```

Comment: This is the most useful answer for me. The original poster (like me) *already had a token* - it just did not work as expected.

All the answers starting with "generate a token" are therefore a bit beside the point. My existing token works fine in other places, so I don't see the need to start all over again.

And all the answers based on `git remote set-url` store your token in a way that is not terribly secure.

My repo wouldn't accept the token at the password prompt, even with a fresh clone, but this worked. Afterwards I just deleted the line from the bash history - no spillage :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Android Studio Arctic Fox Solution (Windows 10)

I was authenticated in Android Studio Arctic Fox (latest version) using a personal access token, but still, I was getting this error on August 14, 2021:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
```

I generated a new access token on github.com, removed my GitHub account from Android Studio, and added the account again with the new access token. But still, it was showing the same error.

Reading other solutions on Stack Overflow, I downloaded the GitHub CLI, and added my GitHub account in the Windows command prompt with the access token successfully, and tried to push the repository from Android Studio again, which again failed.

Then following [this article](https://jimmy-shen.medium.com/august-13-github-requested-url-403-5a03a34721f0), I did the following at the command line:

```
cd <project-directory>
git remote set-url origin https://<TOKEN>@github.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git
```

I pushed again from Android Studio, and it worked finally!

Answer (score 3):

Run these commands inside your project directory if the project was cloned before 13 Aug 2020:

```
git remote set-url <remote_name> <remote_url>
git pull
```

Type your *username* and *personal access token* as the *password*.

Comment: Example -

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myName/GitTest.git

Answer (score 3):

As a security precaution, GitHub automatically removes personal access tokens that haven't been used in a year. To provide additional security, we highly recommend adding expiration to your personal access tokens.

Just follow *[Creating a token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-token)*.

Answer (score 3):

**In three commands**:

First create a token as indicated in the official documentation: *[Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)*

Then reset the Git credentials

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Clone or pull your repositories:

```
`git pull` or `git clone`
```

Then enter the token as your password.

If you want to save your token, you can use:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Mac users**

Generate a token and set it in the keychain.

[This quick video explains it well](https://youtu.be/iKf8-hhdWjs).

**For Windows Users**

Just instead of the keychain, you need to set up [Credential Manager](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/what-is-windows-credential-manager) with the newly generated token.

[Here is a quick video for Windows](https://youtu.be/znLeTzvgla0)

Answer (score 3):

Recently GitHub updated their *remote: Support for password authentication*. Which was removed on August 13, 2021 to use PAT (personal access token) instead for accessing the GitHub API.

You can read about in the blog post [here](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

### Now to enable PAT

- Log in to your GitHub account.
- Follow [this write-up](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) for the next actions.

Now to use the token on the command line, *do* this:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git

Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

**Note** that your token has an expiry time and must be kept privately and used whenever you need to *authenticate* on the command line.

#### Heads up

If your are cloning into a repository that is owned by an:

Organisation

- Make sure your are **member** of that organisation

Or if some personal repository,

- Make sure you have **enabled** the following

**The organisation/personal** will need to ***enable remote cloning and forking*** like so:

- Go to organisation settings:

[image: Settings page]

- Enable member privileges:

  [image: Member privileges page]

Answer (score 3):

For people who want to use [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements):

Just copy like this at the *source* path:

```
https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>
```

[image: Add like your repository like this to the source path]

Comment: You can authenticate in 3 ways:
* Method 1: using `gh auth login`.
* Method 2: using `tokens`, but they are temporary and have an expiration date.
* Method 3: using `SSH keys`.

Personally, I like to use SSH keys better, here is a video on how to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbF6b5Xfh3s

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I have found so far:

1. Install GitHub CLI, `brew install gh` or [check how to install for other OSes](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)
2. Type `gh auth login` in your terminal
3. Follow through like this:

   ```
   What account do you want to log into?
   Choose GitHub.com

   What is your preferred protocol for Git operations?
   Choose HTTPS

   Authenticate Git with your GitHub credentials?
   Choose Yes

   How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI?
   Choose Login with a web browser

   (Copy the one-time code and paste in the browser)

   Press 'Enter' to open github.com in your browser
   ```

Comment: In case someone is looking for way to install brew on Arch based distros:
https://gist.github.com/fardjad/114ebf50a0dd031418bb63b3b134db51

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to clone the project that was always giving this error. The solution I encouraged was, after having generated the token as the post was spoken in the post, I did as described below.

Using a personal access token for the **cloning** of a new project.

For cloning, also you just need to modify the URL as you have done in step 2.

The older way to clone a repository:

```
git clone repository_URL folder_name

git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repository> my_project
```

The new way of cloning with a personal access token:

```
git clone https://<token>@github.com/<user>/<repository> my_project
```

I share my solution.

Answer (score 3):

First you need *SSH Key Based Authentication*

- [Windows Tutorial: SSH Key Authentication](https://GitHub:%20Add%20an%20SSH%20Key)
- [Linux/Mac Tutorial: SSH Key-Based Authentication](https://youtu.be/vpk_1gldOAE)
- [Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

And then

1. [Generate a personal token](https://github.com/settings/tokens)
2. Set your user name: `git config --global user.name "userName"`
3. Set your email address: `git config --global user.email "email"`
4. `git config --global credential.helper cache`
5. `git push`/`git pull` or something user name and password (`personal-token`)

---

You can follow this video: *[Using personal access tokens with Git and GitHub](https://youtu.be/kHkQnuYzwoo)*

Comment: What do you mean by *"something last time need user name and password"* (is incomprehensible)? For instance, is punctuation missing? Are words missing?

Comment: it means next time no need to type the user name and password again,

Answer (score 2):

For those who followed the instruction to generate the **Personal access tokens**, but forgot to select suitable scopes:

Please do remember to choose suitable scopes like repositories. You won't get a different error prompt whether you use the previous password or a new token without a suitable scope.

Comment: Re *"choose suitable scopes like repositories"* (seems incomprehensible): Do you mean *"choose suitable scopes* ***for*** *repositories"*? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68860275/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who uses [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) as the Git client, open *Preferences* → *go to the *Accounts* tab* → *Add GitHub account* → *Auth type = basic* → fill in your GitHub account and the access tokens from GitHub you created as a password → *Use HTTPS protocol* → done!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use SSH (forget https) (E.g., don't use https url for cloning)
2. Use Personal Access Token (PAT) (forget username/password)

> (e.g., Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Token)

3. Update git to latest version (e.g., 2.35.1)  //I think this is important
4. In Github, Uncheck Settings > Developer Settings > Keep my email addresses private

Conclusion: You add Personal Access token in Github. Then from any IDE (e.g., Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA etc.) you can add remote using ssh (e.g.,  name: origin, URL: git@github.com:your_github_username/your_git_repo.git. That's it

If not already done,

5. Configure git global username and email

   > git config --global user.name "your_username" && git config --global user.email "your_email"

**If in windows, you can add windows credentials for your user**, control panel > users > manage your credential > Windows Credentials > Add a generic credential >

> Internet address will be git:https://github.com and you need to type
> in your username and password will be your GitHub Personal Access
> Token => Click Ok and you are done

After this I was able to use git (fetch/push/pull etc.)

Comment: In addition: git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

Answer (score 2):

### For macOS users, just simply follow these steps:

*(I have taken this part [from Kartik Tyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal/68780401#68780401), but I added one of the crucial part that has been missed.)*

1. Go to this link: https://github.com/settings/tokens  (Profile -> settings -> developers setting -> personal access tokens). (don't go to repository setting; it's your profile setting)
2. Generate a new token and copy-paste it somewhere safely.
3. Now search for an app in your Mac, named `Keychain Access`.
4. Search for `github.com`.

**If it is not present:**

5.1. Click on "Create a new Keychain Item" button (the notepad-pen icon).

Keychain Item Name: `https://github.com`

Account Name: `https://github.com` (Must keep it like this. Do not add `www`. It will not work properly then)

Password: *Paste the token you generated*

**If it is present:**

5.2. If there are multiple GitHub logins then choose `Kind: Internet password`, double-click it.

6. Click on show password, then enter your Mac's password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Password should be visible by now. Now, just paste the token you generated in step 2 and click <kbd>Save changes</kbd>.

And that should be it. Enjoy!

Comment: This does not work.  After I do all the steps, running the command `git push -u origin main` on Mac prompts for Username, which I provided, and then Password.  At the Password prompt, I tried by pasting (cmd+V) and [Enter], and that worked.

Comment: High likely I forgot to add this part here. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I had some issues trying to find GitHub on the Keychain in my MacBook. I've tried a lot of ways with no success.

From my perspective, the workaround I've used to be able to pull and push from my GitHub account fast, was doing it by SSH.

This allowed me to do it with no further configuration.

1. You can do it going to *[SSH keys](https://github.com/settings/keys)*
2. Then *New SSH key*
3. If you already created an SSH locally, just run `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in your terminal
4. Then pull, push, clone or whatever you need from your GitHub repository and it's done

I know this is not the solution to the issue, but it worked for me since I needed to do it fast and to me to be honest there isn't any reason that I need to use HTTPS instead of SSH.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Do you already have a ssh generated?
Also, make sure when you are cloning the repo you change. HTTPS to SSH

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a personal access token (PAT) for your account. See [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens) to create your PAT. Your PAT should start with ghp_
2. Open your Keychain Access app, search for GitHub, and delete your existing saved passwords
3. Go back to your terminal and try pushing your commit. It should prompt for your user name and password. Now, try entering your PAT in place of your usual GitHub password/passphrase.

Comment: Why should it start with *"ghp_"*?

Answer (score 1):

Get an access token from GitHub:

GitHub → *Settings* → *Developer settings* → *Personal access tokens* → *Generate a new token*

Copy-paste the new token into [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29).

Open [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) and type the following commands:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain

git clone https://github.com/abc/angularProject.git

Username for 'https://github.com': Test

Password for 'https://test@github.com': (enter your token here)
```

Comment: On Windows, presumably (the last part)?

Answer (score 1):

#### For Mac

If you do not have anything on the keychain for "GitHub", create a new keychain item and add your details. Insert the token from GitHub in place of the password.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours on this issue, with [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) 2 ([Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa)). Opening a new shell worked for me. Trying the old shell, it did not work.

I am also investigating [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab) as maybe they don't have the Microsoft culture of forcing you do to things their way ("You will prefer it this way") or releasing breaking changes all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what really helped, but I know it works for me now. This is everything I've done in order:

1. Generated the [PAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_access_token) and used as password - it didn't work.
2. Cleared the github.com entry in the Windows [Credential Manager](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/what-is-windows-credential-manager) - not working.
3. Added the PAT to the repository URL like this

`https://<personal-access-token>@github.com/<my-repo-url>`

- it worked, but I didn't like this solution.

4. Restarted PC. Installed the newest Git from https://git-scm.com - and in [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) - menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Git* → *Git Version* - selected "System".
5. Removed the PAT from repository URL - it still works.

To me it looks like installing the new "Git" really helped, so step 3 may be unnecessary, but I can't be sure about that. I don't know if it would work without temporarily adding PAT to the URL. Maybe it also saved something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Mac or Linux, install GH via [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)):

```bash
brew install gh
```

If you have installed and run `gh auth login` and still have that issue, the easiest way of solving it is just running:

```bash
gh auth setup-git
```

Comment: What is "GH"? The GitHub desktop application? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The most annoying thing with the PAT is that they expire quite rapidly. You get an expiry notice email and it has to be renewed. If you have several repo's cloned locally, you have to update the PAT in the .git/config in all of them and you're bound to forget some of them, which then don't work anymore (for pushing).

Typically you would have in `<repo>/.git/config` of every cloned repo:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
    pushurl = https://<PAT>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

If you instead use the [include] facility of [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) and the url-rewriting of [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_git_urls), then the PAT can be stored in a single file, for instance `~/github.git`. You have only static data in `<repo>/.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
# remove the pushurl = https://<PAT>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
[include]
    path = ~/github.git
```

and the PAT centrally in `~/github.git`, which is the only file that needs editing when the PAT is renewed:

```
[url "https"//<PAT>@github.com/<user>/"]
    pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/<user>/
```

Tested and works very nicely.

Probably, you could also just put the [url] pushInsteadOf in your per-user git config file `~/.gitconfig` and you don't need to use [include] in the per-repo config.

On the other hand, the 'ssh://' method still works too and has none of the problems of PAT. Just put your ssh public-key in your github account.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answers to this question suffice to solve the problem. I just want to clarify one thing that I faced. If `git remote set-url` gives you the error message `error: No such remote 'origin'`, you may need to add the remote origin first. So, to sum up, the steps are as follows:

1. On GitHub, Go to Settings > Developer Settings. Then generate an access token.
2. Run `git remote add origin <repo_url>`
3. Run `git remote set-url origin https://<TOKEN>@github.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git`
4. Run `git clone https://github.com/<repo_url>.git`
5. *Asks for username and password.* Put your GitHub username and generated access token (**as password**) in respective places.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) user and fixed it by "Refresh OAuth Token" in menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Authentication* → select GitHub Account.

[image]

If you have never added authentication for your GitHub account, you can refer to it on *[How to Connect GitHub with SourceTree](https://www.awordfromnet.com/how-to-connect-github-with-sourcetree/)* (Method 1: Connect with Remote Account via OAuth).

Answer (score -1):

I changed my default browser from Google Chrome to Safari and it fixed it.