# Github push origin master and Token authentication

Tags: github, github-actions

Before today I update my git repo with the following commands:

```
git add -A

git commit -a -m 

push origin master
```

and after the last command I insert my Github username and password.
As you know, from today it is no longer possible to use this type of authentication and I'm not at all familiar with Github so I wanted to ask you if you can show me step by step how to update my repo because I can't understand this token authentication thing (yes I'm a stupid).

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776300/github-change-from-password-to-person-access-token-without-re-cloning-the-repo/68776344#68776344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is create a Personal Access Token and use it as a password.

Follow this guide to find out how to create a PAT.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Answer (score 1):

Create a token as [described by github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). Using token instead of password:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username
Password: your_token
```

You can also use token in url, no prompt then:

```
git push https://your_token@github.com/my_github_account/my_repo.git
```