# Use token to push some code to GitHub - "Support for password authentication was removed"

Tags: github, token

Error message when using `git push`:

> Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
> remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/codingTheWorld777/react-mini-projects.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"***

I cannot use my token to access GitHub, so how can I push code to GitHub?

Comment: though `git push` or some lib? besides, follow the link it, read the page it tells you what you need to do. tldr, see: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: When I use **git push** though. I added a picture in the description.

Comment: Yeah I have read the link but I am not sure that is my case. I have created a token and in the doc, I don't see anything that show me how to use token for git credential :<

Comment: ok, follow the link above, basically, the token you create (instructions in the link) replaces the password value that you would normally enter ([ref](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#using-a-token-on-the-command-line)). If your developing locally there should be no reason not to use public-key SSH, you only need add it once then you don't need to use usernames or passwords for any git action on any repo.

Comment: Gotcha. I just need to delete my github password in keychain in order to re-sign in to github credential :) . Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have not a public SSH key in your settings? If so, switch to SSH via git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git

Answer (score 52, accepted):

GitHub announced their intent to require the use of token-based authentication for all authenticated Git operations. They will no longer accept account passwords when authenticating Git operations on GitHub.com:

**Generate token:**

- Go to your GitHub account [token settings](https://github.com/settings/tokens)
- Generate a token

**On Mac:**

- Go to keychain Access
- Press the *Login* tab and all items
- Click GitHub key
- Change the password to the recent generated token

[image]

**On Windows:**

- Go to *Control Panel* → *User Accounts* → *Credential Manager*
- Edit the *Generic Credential* of GitHub
- Paste the token instead of the password

[image]

Comment: Show man, running on mac with this tip

Comment: Github not identifying this crucial step for Mac users in their documentation and/or error message is probably costing hundreds or thousands of developer hours.

Comment: This is not a good solution for MacOS users. It replaces your login credentials for safari, and may break subsequent third party oauth links to your github account depending on token permissions.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaKolden, thanks for that info, whats the good way to fix that for MacOS then ?

Comment: @AhmedImam So far the only solution I can recommend is to use ssh auth and avoid the global account token altogether. Most answers that involve using token auth are significantly less secure (embedding your token in a world readable repo, `ps` visible command line arguments, bash history, etc) and higher maintenance effort. This is seriously the strangest security roll out I've ever seen.

Comment: @JoshuaKolden I totally agree. @AhmedImam Your Mac OSX solution is wrong. You don't change "Internet Password" that's just for browser usage. You have to add an entry with `name=git:https://github.com`, `Kind=Programme password`, Account=your github username, `where=git:https://github.com`. The cleanest way to do this however is to `brew install gh` and then run `gh auth login`. This adds the **correct** entry into your keychain (cf. solution from @Niyaz).

Comment: @Thomas I tried "brew install gh" and "gh auth login" as u recommended but it eventually change the "Internet Password" of github.com password to the token.  can u please be more detailed or post your answer in the main question, this one already marked as duplicated, then provide the link here.

Comment: @AhmedImam this solution has already been posted by **Niyaz**. I think his/her solution as **Joshua Kolden**'s solution are the correct ones. The above solution involving manually changing entries in keychains is not good or even reliable.

Comment: @JoshuaKolden could you please post your solution so that people can use it/comment on it/evaluate it?

Comment: @Thomas I can't because it's closed.

Answer (score 24):

You need to change the remote URL with:

```
git remote set-url <stream> https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>
```

`token` can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: What is stream? Can you please guide little about stream?

Comment: @Habib Stream is a branching model. If you want to push code in master branch, the  `master` will be your main stream.

Comment: I tried the same command by adding 'origin' or my origin name to set the URL for it.

Answer (score 21):

I also encounter this problem today, on **macOS**.

I solve this problem by:

First, get a token! Follow the guidance of GitHub. I think you can just click the link provided in the warning.

Second, change the key chain on **macOS**:

1. Search "Keychain" on macOS.
2. Search "GitHub".
3. Change the password in the one that with "Internet Password", **using your new token**.

Then, my problem is solved and I can "git push" now.

Comment: thanks, it helped. The other thing we need to take care of is to generate a token every time the token expires or we generate a token that never expires.

Comment: Thx a lot! This is essentially the same as this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68776344/15250330

Comment: Change the password in the one that with "Internet Password", using your new token. did the trick for me

Comment: i think may be go to github.com enter your credentials and save the info in keychain. then check

Comment: @yanjieZe and @AhmadShahwaiz: Your Mac OSX solution is wrong. You do not need to change "Internet Password" that's just for browser usage (and has nothing to do with the OP). You have to add an entry with `name=git:https://github.com`, `Kind=Programme password`, Account=your github username, `where=git:https://github.com`. The cleanest way to do this however is to `brew install gh` and then run `gh auth login`. This adds the **correct** entry into your keychain (cf. @niyaz's solution).

Answer (score 16):

Step 1: Go to your GitHub account → *Settings* → *Developer settings* → *Personal access tokens* → Generate / regenerate your token

Step 2: Go to https://cli.github.com and download GitHub CLI

Step 3: Go to your command line or Terminal → **gh auth login** and follow with login credentials. Done.

Comment: Only this worked for me. PAT generated ---> in keychain there is NO "Internet Password" entry!!! So I ran `brew install gh`, then executed the above command and chose the appropriate options (the PAT needs rights for `repo` + `workflow` + `admin:read:org`) then pasted in the PAT, and done. I can now call `git pull`, `git push`, _etc._ from bash.

Comment: @Niyaz your answer is the only correct one so far for Mac OSX esp. regarding the OP.

Comment: @Thomas, just tried out with Windows 10, seems working fine with the above steps, in Windows, Step 1: https://cli.github.com/ - CLI downloaded for windows
Step 2: in Windows Terminal `gh auth login` 
once Logged in successful with username, then i could able to push the commits..

Comment: brilliant! I was only able to say that your solution works under Mac OSX. But given that you've now checked on windows (I assume that bash for windows is installed?) then your solution is imo the cleanest and best.

Comment: how do I make this gh interact with my local git installation?

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem. For me the solution was install the GitHub CLI in https://cli.github.com/. After installing in my OS, I ran `gh auth login` in my terminal and logged in through the browser with the access token that I generated in the GitHub profile. Follow:

*My Account* → *Settings* → *Developer settings* → *Personal access tokens* [GENERATE NEW TOKEN]

Comment: Thanks : ) Only this worked for me. PAT generated ---> in mac osx keychain there is NO "Internet Password" entry!!! So I ran `brew install gh`, then executed the above command and chose the appropriate options (the PAT needs rights for `repo` + `workflow` + `admin:read:org`) then pasted in the PAT, and done. I can now call `git pull`, `git push`, _etc._ from bash.

Comment: Only this solution worked on mac (Y)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you need to create a personal access token in *[Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)*

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git

Username: your_username

Password: your_token
```

Comment: most people already know this and your answer does not address the main issue in the OP. The problem is _permanently_ setting the credentials, so that one can call `git pull` and `git push` from a bash terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Mac:

First generate a token from GitHub. And replace your password with the token from the keychain access in the GitHub section.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your Mac OSX solution is plain **wrong**. You do not need to change "Internet Password" that's just for browser usage. You have to add an entry with `name=git:https://github.com`, `Kind=Programme password`, Account=your github username, `where=git:https://github.com`. But the cleanest way to do this however is to `brew install gh` and then run `gh auth login`. This adds the **correct** entry into your keychain (cf. @niyaz's solution).

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a personal access token. You can find the instructions on creating personal access token in *[Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)*

Make sure you keep the access token secure & secret. After that you need to replace your current saved password in the device (laptop/desktop) with the access token. In macOS you can search for Keychain and find GitHub with an Internet password and replace it with your access token. For instructions, see *[Updating credentials from the macOS Keychain](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)*.

In Windows, it might be [Credential Manager](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/what-is-windows-credential-manager) (I'm not sure). Check this out: *[How to update your Git credentials on Windows](https://cmatskas.com/how-to-update-your-git-credentials-on-windows/)*