# How do I switch my github repos to token based authentication instead of using passwords?

Tags: git, authentication, github, passwords

I know github has been sending warnings about this for quite some time, however, I never got around to it and I still can not figure it out.

Most of my repos I work on my home desktop. Some projects if I work away from home on them, I will clone to my laptop so I can take with me. On these cloned repos I have been authenticating with my github login and password with each push.

I know I am supposed to authenticate with a Personal Access Token... and I have followed the steps on github to do so... and I have added the PAT to the windows credentials in the control panel.

NOW when I try to push my repo from my laptop it still prompts me to authenticate with login and password. From what I've read I am supposed to enter my github login name and THEN THE PAT that was generated for me... however I can not get anything to work for the life of me. When I do all of this it tells me that passwords are depreciated and I need to set up a PAT... :( I have been working on this for hours and I am at a loss. Can someone help me continue using github? I am very frustrated and confused as to why they would make this a necessary step to continue accessing our projects. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68779977/9206831

Comment: @YuhLee That's it, I found it almost as soon as I got desperate and made this post - thank you so much for your response!