# cant get command line authorization for github

Tags: git, github

on windows computer.

I ran

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/santiagoziel/mezcal.git
git push -u origin master
```

Then i got the promt to log in with my username and password, but when i tried using them i got:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/santiagoziel/mezcal.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

i went to the link and i followed the steps to create my "Personal access token" and then as instructed i tried to use that instead of my password, but i got the same message.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to) answer your question?

Comment: the problem is i'm already am using the token instead of the password, and ive already have manager as my credintial helper

Comment: Either you're not using the token and you have a saved password in the credential manager, or you're inserting unexpected characters into the prompt field and what you're pasting is not a valid token.  Otherwise, you wouldn't be getting this error.  You probably need to flush your credential manager as specified in that answer.

Comment: mmm ok ill check maybe the way im copying and pasting the token is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN>@github.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git
git push -u origin master
```