# Git does not allow pull request after personal access token generation

Tags: git, github

Recently, I setup a personal access token for my account as instructed [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

However, when I try `git pull` from my CLI I get the following error:

```
user@HP-Pavilion-dv5:/home/user/Documents/research/dataCollection# git pull
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/accountName.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I had my credential saved in the config file, hence it does not ask for the username and password by default.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)