# What's git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master

Tags: controls, version, message, atlassian-sourcetree

I can't find any information in the internet for this. I'm using sourcetree. This link is the nearest I've found and it doesn't help : https://dev.to/shafia/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-token-instead-4nbk. Could someone advice?

I want to post all my programming items to github. I've been using sourcetree for many years. atlassian website only had for macintosh. I had to test all kinds of things as there was no proper manual for windows. I succeeded but it was very troublesome and tedious.

Comment: Solution found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68780819/when-i-try-to-pull-or-push-in-github-i-am-getting-an-error-message-please-use?rq=2

Answer (score 0):

Enter the directory of the current error repository,try gitbash command:

```
git config http.sslVerify "false"
```

When you access the Git remote repository through HTTPS, if the server's SSL certificate is not signed by a third-party organization (for example: CA...), then Git will report an error. The reason is that unknown uncertified signed certificates represent potentially significant risks. The above command is a good solution for Git to handle trusted SSL certificates. It limits the setting of ignoring certificate errors to specific repositories to avoid potential security risks caused by expanding the scope of application that should be set.

I hope it works.