# GitHub - How to clone repository on a shared server without giving access too all my repos

Tags: github, ssh-keys

My question is the same as [Github add SSH key from others will grant access to all repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68785724/github-add-ssh-key-from-others-will-grant-access-to-all-repos), except my use case is that I am working on a shared server with other contributors. We all need access to a certain repository on this server. However, since GitHub requires SSH now, how can I clone and use the repository without adding my SSH key to the server and allowing everyone else access to all of my personal repositories?

I have already added my teammates as contributors in the repo we want to clone; it would be nice if we could each individually use our username and passwords to interface with the repo (like the old HTTPS method of cloning git repositories) without having to share our private keys with each other. If there is an option to only allow SSH access to a specific repo, that would be nice as well.

The only workaround I can think of right now is to create a dummy GitHub account with the sole purpose of accessing this repo, and registering our SSH key with that GitHub account. But this seems very contrived and I'm wondering if there is a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dummy github account with only the right permissions to access the one repo is what GitHub calls a Machine Account and is the recommended way to provide access under scenarios like these.

Alternatively, you could use a deploy token, those are bound to a single repo by default.

Comment: Thanks! I used a deploy key and that worked. For reference, I followed https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys and https://gist.github.com/zhujunsan/a0becf82ade50ed06115