# Git is saying 403 when trying to perform the git push origin master command

Tags: git, github

All help is appreciated as it has been 3 hours and I am still unable to have a clear connection to my github account.

**Error:**

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/location.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

**How to get this error:**

`git push origin master`

**Steps taken to fix this error:**

1. Updated my git using brew
2. Follow Git documentation to use SSH in
   order to create connection
3. Used `sh -T git@github.com` to make sure
   the connection exist. It does.

I understand password has been deprecated when using the command line but I also don't understand why it is still being requested whenever I try to use `git push origin master`

I also understand 403 means you don't have rights. So I did logout and log back in to my github to make sure I have the correct password being used (even though it is deprecated)

All help is really helpful with this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: git usually outputs more of the response from the server. What did it say?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using an HTTPS URL as a remote.  That means that you will be pushing to or pulling from a remote over HTTPS, not SSH.

If you've been using a password for HTTPS with GitHub, then the reason you cannot pull or push is that doing that is no longer allowed, and you should [follow the directions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to/68775982) to switch to a personal access token.

If you'd like to use SSH instead, you will need to change the URL.  You can do that by running `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:{username}/{location}.git`.  Then Git will know that you want to use SSH, and if your SSH keys are correctly set up, it will work.

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer. I did find out that I needed to use a Personal Access Token but your answer helped me solve it by using the SSH approach. Since the Personal Access Token I would need to create a new one every 7-30 days. Thank you so much for this one.

Answer (score 3):

Open Credentials Manager and check if any credentials exists for git or GitHub there. If yes remove them and try to login again with fresh credentials.