# Creating a personal access token

Tags: github

I wanted to push a repository on GitHub and here was the response:

> The support for password authentication was removed, please use a personal access token instead

How do I create a personal access token?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Github removed support for password authentication on August 13, 2021.

You can create the token using this documentation

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

and you can read more on the similar question asked already on this platform. using this link.

[Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

Comment: Yes, i had to create individual PATs for my machines because you can't recover it after its used unless you save or copy somewhere