# Github password authentication was removed. How to connect Git within RStudio to Github (Without terminal commands) using the Personal Access Token?

Tags: github, passwords, rstudio, token, commit

I am using the RStudio server and have connected the RStudio to Github. I used to commit and push the changes of files within RStudio. However, since 13 August I got the message that "Github password authentication was removed issue on August 13" and have been asked to use the personal access token. I have generated the token from Github.com following this link

[using personal token](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/)

The problem is how to connect the RStudio to Github using the personal access token so I can do the commits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

Comment: @bk2204 I had checked that post, unfortunately it did not solve my issue. So what I want is not using the terminal command line, but using the git directly which is installed already in RStudio. Using the Git menu options [RStudio] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WELaPjS_ekFx5_r6fDeTWlrBMf_e0VGS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you're using a standard credential manager, then doing it from the command line should solve your problem for you, and there may not be a way to do it in RStudio.  Or maybe there is, but nobody here knows what it is.

Comment: @bk2204 Alright, it was simple using the username and the password, but now using the personal access token, there must be a way but so far I could not find any information out there.

Comment: Well, set it up the same way, except provide the PAT as the password.

Comment: @bk2204 I did it already. However, it still has error. I tried to commit one specific file but it always committing all changes for all files in the same directory and somehow failed because there are some large files. It never happend before the PAT thing.