# git-credential-osxkeychain wants to access key "github.com" in your keychain

Tags: git

In line with the github recently removing support for password authentication - I have created a PAT following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

However, everytime I `git push` I see that that the "authencity of git-credential-osxkeychain cannot be verified.

Why this? Surely I don't need to enter my password **everytime I push?**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OSX prompts for a password every time you use `git` after `brew` upgrades `git`. To make Keychain Access trust `git` with the password again, you have to open Keychain Access, search for github under Keychain: login, kind: Internet password, and add the new path to `git-credential-osxkeychain`. Or, just delete the github password and regenerate the Personal Access Token again. (source: [Fixing the git-credential-osxkeychain password prompts on every git transaction](https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2019/11/fixing-git-credential-osxkeychain.html)
)

For example, today `brew` installed `git-credential-osxkeychain` to `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.36.0/libexec/git-core/git-credential-osxkeychain`, so I had to add that path to the password in Keychain Access.

```
$ brew info git
…
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.36.0 (1,544 files, 43.6MB) *
…
$ find /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.36.0 -name git-credential-osxkeychain
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.36.0/libexec/git-core/git-credential-osxkeychain
```

[image: Screenshot of password window in Keychain Access]

Comment: Thanks!  Worked for me.  Here's a fish shell expression that points to the right file:
`$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/Cellar/git/(string split " " (git --version))[3]/libexec/git-core/git-credential-osxkeychain`

Comment: I am not clear about what I need to change in the Keychain Access? After I ran the "find" command, I saw this: "usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>"
Is there an additional command I have to run?

Comment: PS How exactly do I add this path to the Keychain Access?

Comment: @MariannaS., once you find the path to git-credential-osxkeychain, you don’t execute it. Instead, you copy the path and paste it into the modal dialog that shows up when you click the `+` button.

Answer (score 5):

You can enter your password and click “Always Allow,” which should avoid you needing to enter the password again.

The likely reason for this is that your version of Git comes from Homebrew or another source that doesn't sign its packages, and Apple is complaining about this.  As far as I'm aware, nobody but Apple ships a version of Git that's signed, and Homebrew is considered reputable, so there's no reason to be worried here.  The notification is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

https cloning has always been fraught with peril and you'll see issues like this .. additionally, Microsoft Corporation (who acquired GitHub in 2018) is attempting to frustrate you into using their command line tool by both hiding ssh clone and only appearing to offer clone via https or [their command line tool](https://github.com/cli/cli)

See [Embrace, Extend, and Extinguish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish)

Create ssh keys and clone via ssh instead of https

- create a new key pair if you don't have one

  ```sh
  $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
  ```

  [GitHub docs for this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
- [Add the public key to your account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
- clone the repo again using an ssh remote

  ```
  git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
  ```

  or update the existing repo's remote to the ssh version

  ```
  git remote -v  # show existing remote
  git remote set-url git@github.com:user/repo.git
  ```