# brew installation error after denying keychain access

Tags: git, homebrew, keychain

I am trying to install a few packages using brew in my MacOS Monterey version 12.4. While install 'g++' using the following command

```
brew install g++
```

The following prompt popped up asking for my keychain password to allow access.

```
git-credential-osxkeychain wants to use your confidential information stored in "github.com" in your keychain.
The authenticity of "git-credential-osxkeychain" cannot be verified. Do you want to allow access to this item?
Always Allow | Deny | Allow
```

I accidentally pressed "Deny" and now I can't install anymore packages using brew.

The following error pops up

```
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

The same error is occurring if I try to any other package through brew. I reset my keychain credentials and also re-added github.com to keychain access.

I tried

```
brew doctor
```

and the following are the warnings:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/sanleypeter/opt/anaconda3/bin/icu-config

...
...

Warning: Unbrewed '.la' files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected '.la' files:
  /usr/local/lib/libjags.la
  /usr/local/lib/libjrmath.la

Warning: Unbrewed '.pc' files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected '.pc' files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/jags.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
  /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
```

But I don't thing any of these warning are related. I've also tried using

```
rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
```

Is there anything I can do to resolve this? Or should I re-install brew and try it again?

Comment: Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868084/git-credential-osxkeychain-wants-to-access-key-github-com-in-your-keychain) at the marked answer. You might be able to add the `git-credential-osxkeychain` to the Keychain item