# I don't understerstand how I can use git with HTTPS without having to type in my password every time?

Tags: git

As far as I know, when you use git with https, you would have to type in your password every time you make a request to github unless you use SSH or you store your credentials locally on your computer with git config credential.helper store .

I've been using HTTPS but never have to type in my credentials. When I run git config --list it only shows my email and my name, but not my password. Can anyone explain to me why I am not required to type in my password or where it could be stored?

Comment: Is target repo private ? If not, it is normal to be able to `clone`, `fetch` and `pull` without credentials. They would be required to `push`

Comment: The credentials will not show up in `git config --list` (user.name and user.email are only used for commits' author and committer fields), they will show up in `git remote -v` (the url you use to access your remote, it will at least mention if you use a username when connecting to the remote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been using HTTPS but never have to type in my credentials.

That is probably because your credentials are *already* cached by a credential helper.

1. Check what yours is: `git config --global credential.helper`
2. Check what credentials are stored:

In a Git bash session:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-xxx get
```

Replace `xxx` by the value returned by `git config --global credential.helper`.

If it is empty, and if the remote URL is an HTTPS one, then, as suggested by [LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280309/i-dont-understerstand-how-i-can-use-git-with-https-without-having-to-type-in-my/74280785?noredirect=1#comment131143744_74280785), Git might still be using SSH anyway with [an `url.<base>.pushInsteadOf` directive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf).
Check that with:

```
git config --show-origin --list --show-scope | grep -i insteadOf
```

The OP adds in the comments:

> running `git config --show-origin --list` gives me, among other things, `file:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig    credential.helper=osxkeychain`
> So it could look like it is stored in my osxkeychain?

If that is the case:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-osxkeychain get
```

See also "[Updating credentials from the macOS Keychain](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)".

Comment: Hm `git config --global credential.helper` doesn't return anything (running it on my MacBook Air M1)

Comment: @BorisGrunwald What is the remote URL of your local repository? (`git remote -v` inside the repo folder)

Comment: `origin  https://github.com/jikol1906/sentence-guesser-react.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/jikol1906/sentence-guesser-react.git (push)`

Comment: It is a private repo

Comment: @BorisGrunwald Then you must enter your credentials on each push, no?

Comment: No I don't have to. Really have no idea what is going on.

Comment: @BorisGrunwald  Do you see your credentials in your environment variables (`env`)? Or in a `rc` files? (`.bashrc` or `.curlrc`)

Comment: @BorisGrunwald: `git config --show-origin --list | grep insteadOf` ?

Comment: @LeGEC running `git config --show-origin --list` gives me, among other things, `file:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig    credential.helper=osxkeychain` So it could look like it is stored in my osxkeychain?

Comment: @BorisGrunwald True. I should have checked the other scopes. That is why I suggested in my edited answer `git config --show-origin --list --show-scope`.

Comment: @BorisGrunwald Of interest: "[`git-credential-osxkeychain` wants to access key "`github.com`" in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68868084/6309)".