# Authentication failed when using Github PAT with Sourcetree

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Sourcetree version 3.4.6.

I have followed the instructions for this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781050/68571). I get the token and in Tools => Options => Authentication tab I click on the Add text:

[image]

I use the PAT as password but I get a "Authentication failed" message.

How can I use PAT with SourceTree?

Answer (score 0):

You should first authenticate with your default browser on your github account with your credentials (or just check if you're already authenticated), then choose in the SourceTree app the "OAuth" authentication instead of the Basic then click "Refresh OAuth token". Now you should be able to enter successfully to your github repos.