# git push not working , error is "The requested URL returned error: 403"

Tags: git, github

i am learning git veriosn control and trying to push code to repository ,but i am facing two erros

**1:remote: Permission to username/repo name denied to "username".**

**2 fatal: unable to access https://github.com/username/repositoryname/: The requested URL returned error: 403****

Comment: Did you create a user token? GitHub no longer allows authentication with a user name and password, so many tutorials are out of date.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice when i click sign-in in vs code i am given two options github or Microsoft i clicked on github then i click on "Authorize Visual Studio Code to access GitHub" continue  then i am given token but it says if u are not redirected automatically add token manually so i click on open visual studio from github page and get signed in successfully

Comment: Signing in to VS Code is entirely separate from authenticating Git operations.

Comment: There is no `https:` access to a github repo using a password.

Comment: Might be useful to read: [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

Answer (score 3):

You need to authenticate with GitHub. (This is NOT the same as signing into VS Code.) In short, you either need to generate an SSH key or a personal access key. See https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github#authenticating-with-the-command-line for details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible causes for this problem:

1. You typed an incorrect password. Make sure you are using the correct GitHub password for the account. The Git client on the A2 Hosting server requires a modified HTTPS URL to work correctly.
2. Make sure you have access to the repo.

Comment: in vscode i signed in the the same account to which the repository belongs to , when i sync the account then i was redirected back to vscode  , where was i suppoed to provide password