# Unable to install plugins in vim via PlugInstall

Tags: git, vim-plugin, neovim

I use windows. When I try to install `nvim-comp` using `vim-plug` it's giving me this error:

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\nvim\plugged\nvim-comp'...
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-comp.git/'
```

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to) post. I know this might be the github issue but when I try to clone the repository it's working fine. Please help me out if you can.

Comment: I just move the `nvim-cmp` directory which I cloned to `~/Appdata/Local/nvim/plugged`. Even that's not working.

Comment: What is not clear in "Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information."?

Answer (score 2):

It was a typo in `plugin.vim`. It's `nvim-cmp`.