# fatal: repository not found, after I created and added Personal Access Token

Tags: git

- I'm working on ubuntu 18
- I created a new git repository.
- I added some files and created a commit.
- I have tried to push the last commit with my `username` and `git password` and got the following error message:

  **remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead**
- I followed the instructions from: [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to) :
- I generated a new token
- I configured my `username` and `email`
- Now I have tried to push the last commit with my `username` and I used the created token as `password`. Now I got a new error:

  **remote: Repository not found**

1. What am I missing ?
2. How can I push to my git repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this command**

replace the fields as

- your-personal-access-token with your generated personnel access token
- your-username with your github username
- your-repo with the name of the repo in which you want to push

Check whether you have provided repo access to your personel access token

```
git remote set-url origin https://your-personel-access-token@github.com/your-username/your-repo.git
```

Comment: I didn't give repo access to my personal access token. Thanks !