# Unable to resolve to github in a linux vm

Tags: linux, azure, github, virtual-machine

I am new to cloud and azure stuff. I have created a Linux Ubuntu vm in azure. I have been able to connect to it, but I can't resolve to github from within the vm. I have generated a key in github and reset the vm and github passwords but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765

Answer (score 0):

You have the error:  "`github support for password authentication was removed on august 13`".
You need to create a PAT to authenticate to github.
Please refer to [this link on how to create and use PAT.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)