# Git Push gives repository not found error

Tags: git, github

I got a repository  git clone and trying to commit the code.
But getting `remote: Repository not found e`rror

I followed following steps.

**Steps**

```
#git clone https://<YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE>@github.com/<YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE>/<REPO>.git    
#git remote rm origin
#git remote add origin  https://<user>:<pwd>@<repo url>
# git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

# git push --set-upstream origin master
remote: Repository not found
```

.

Can somebody point me right steps?
I have full permission(read/write) for this repository. Problem occured, because one developer locally created initial repository and committed. So, when I clone that repo and do development, i face issue when pushing the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

Comment: @Renat Not really.. I tried token instead of my pw too. But same errors i face..I'm actually confused with the steps now..I look for clear steps..I'm trying this for hours now but couldn't find proper way to commit the code

Comment: What scopes does your token have?  Also, putting the token in the URL is insecure, so you should [use a credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials).

Comment: what happens when you do `git clone https://<user>:<pwd>@<repo url>`?

Comment: could you show us `.git/config` please.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik with password it gives Cloning into 'delwp-api-mule-utilities-api-v1'...
fatal: unable to access'XXXXXX': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL . WIthout password only with username it is cloning fine

Comment: @Faesal I dont see .git file inside my repo..Where it resides?

Comment: it's hidden file, you can access it with terminal

Comment: @Faesal It says access is denied, when try to read content as # type .git

Comment: You'll need to investigate on the web server side what's broken with its configuration. This is not a git issue.