# Problems with git pushing in Clion

Tags: c++, git, clion

I have a problem while I am pushing my committed changes to github. Whenever I do so I need to authorize my GitHub account in CLion. As far as I'm concerned logging via website was removed from the available options so it is necessary to do it with a Token. I generated it many times, but every time I did it there was a message:

"Push failed
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
Authentication failed for 'https://github.com...' "

I use Clion version 2021.2.2. and it is like the software couldn't authorize my github account

Can anybody help me fix this problem?

Comment: You should change your `git remote` when using token.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780401/4688321

Comment: Changing git remote helped and now everything works, thank you