# Why do I get a 'User name not found' error with the GitHub access token?

Tags: linux, github

I'm trying to use the access token with GitHub. I'm trying to follow the following commands. A link for which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to).

For Linux based Operating Systems:
For Linux, you need to configure the local GIT client with a username and password.

`$ git config --global user.name "your-github-username"`

`$ git config --global user.email "your-github-email"`

`git config -l`

But when I use the username command, I get a 'command not found' error. I'm probably missing something completely trivial, but I cannot seem to get it working.

I get the following error message.

`Username for 'http://github.com' : 'my_username' username: command not found`

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71234018/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: E.g., the first image is a screenshot of part of the referenced Stack Overflow answer. Why?? Is the formatting of the text too difficult?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have made an edit to this question in an attempt to gain posting privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting and command block in the answer your were following were confusing. I corrected them and now they read as follows:

> ```
> $ git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
> > Cloning into `YOUR-REPOSITORY`...
> Username: <type your username>
> Password: <type your password or personal access token (GitHub)
> ```

The command you execute is `git clone ...` and the CLI is then going to **interactively** ask for your username and password (PAT for GitHub). Enter this information when asked and confirm with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.