# problem when fix error git : "Support for password authentication was removed", there are no github internet password in Keychain Access?

Tags: git, macos, authentication, github, personal-access-token

I installed git on my Mac and checked it on terminal by command git version, it showed me this :

```
git version 2.35.1
```

So maybe it is ok.

When I tried to push a folder to git, it showed me an error :remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.

And I checked on stackoverflow, here is the link I follow

[Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKf8-hhdWjs

My problem is, when I open the Keychain Access, it only show me GitHub application password, there is no Internet Password ?

So, maybe what I was doing wrong ? Or how can I install the Internet Password to Mac ?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> it only show me GitHub application password,

You should replace that password by a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), created:

- with [repo scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes)
- with or without an expiration date.

That way, you won't get the error message.

Comment: Thank you in advance. I can solve my problem now.