# Why can't I push changes from BlueJ to GitHub?

Tags: java, github, bluej

I have stumbled upon the problem that when I try to push something to my repository through BlueJ (I have connected the BlueJ file with the repository by entering my GitHub credentials), the following error occurs:

"The operation was not authorised by the server. Check your username, password and repository in team settings"

What can I do to solve this problem?

My Repository:
https://github.com/zkurs4np/gitserver

I tried to push a change to my repository and ended up not being able to because of said error.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check, do you for sure have access to that repository? Do you own it?

If that's the case then one thing you can try is to create a [personal access token and use that](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead of your password. I haven't used BlueJ in a while, but GitHub recently stopped allowing using passwords and now requires access tokens, [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to). BlueJ may not have been updated since then.

Comment: There were two reasons for this not working:
1. The personal access token like you mentioned, I entered it but it still didn't work
2. It seems like BlueJ wants you to also enter your email in the username field