# How do I push git even after using PAT

Tags: git, github

I tried to push some command to remote GitHub, even after using the PAT (personal access token) I'm still facing this problem. please help.

```
C:\Users\adegu\projectwork>git push
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Username for 'https://github.com': Mr-Art-coder
Password for 'https://Mr-Art-coder@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a 
personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git- 
operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Mr-Art-coder/projectwork.git/'
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? It seems your Git config/environment is still using your old credentials with your username/password.

Comment: Check the instructions here depending on your OS: [Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH-TOKEN" http(s)://HOSTNAME/api/v3/users/codertocat -I
HTTP/2 200
X-OAuth-Scopes: repo, user
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: user
```

Pay attention to your X-OAuth-Scopes: