# How to reauthenticate using Github Personal Access Token, PAT has expired?

Tags: github, personal-access-token, git-authentication

The PAT that I used for the past month has expired, I am unable to push changes to the repository, how should I go about creating a new token or reauthenticate using my password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. There is a regenerate token button that allows to set a new end-date, but it doesn't produce a new PAT nor re-vive the old PAT.
The only thing that worked for me is generate a new token and replace them in the .git/config files (or use the equivalent git config command).

All in all, I think using an SSH url with github (git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git) and publishing your public SSH key as authorized key in github is much more proven and convenient, even though github (microsoft) doesn't encourage it.

See also [Message "Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal/75621722#75621722) for a convenient method to change the expired PAT centrally.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the old token using link below. Replace "new_token" with the new token you generated and "username" with you github username. Thats what I ussually do.

```
git remote set-url origin https://new_token@github.com/username/repository.git
```