# Git push can saying authentication failed even though I am entering right credentials

Tags: git, github

So basically I am doing a git push and for some reason I am getting error message as:

[image]

When it asks me for my credentials, which are correct because I just used them to logon to my github account. Then it asks me for my ssh credentials for some reason even though i am using https for the remote connection, I enter my git logins into that and get:
[image]

I didn't have this problem with credentials before, so no idea why it's happening now. I even created PATs and used them as passwords still same errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The message in the log says that Support for password authentication was removed. 
Pls Check this answer:
[Message "Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal)