# I cannot push to repository, I get error "Support for password authentication was removed" but I generated a classic token

Tags: windows, git, github

I reviewed this answer here:
[Message "Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal)

But I still get error

```
PS C:\Js Projects> git push -u origin main
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/zac/FindCommonItems.git/'
```

I generated a classic token with all permissions and I set it in Windows 11 credential manager like that

[image]

In VS Code when I run

```
git push -u origin main
```

I get the same error above. What I am missing?

Comment: I get some lines if I used this:
usage: git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
  or: git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
   or: git remote set-url --delete <name> <url>

Comment: Sorry, I missed the <name> part while pressing backspace too long time `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:zac/FindCommonItems.git`

Comment: This error when I try to push:

git@github.com/zac/FindCommonItems.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Worked thanks to [@273K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6752050/273k) like this:

```
Deleted .git folder
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:zac/FindCommonItems.git
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com/zac/FindCommonItems.git
git push -u origin main
```

It prompt also to authenticate from browser

Comment: You're calling `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:zac/FindCommonItems.git` after you deleted `.git` directory. This has no right to do anything. Didn't you get an error on this command?

Comment: At the end you're still using https url.