# Nothing's changed even after adding an SSH key to GitHub

Tags: github, ssh-keys, git-push

I followed the [documentation on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh) to set up an SSH key for automatic authentication. The proof that I have set it up correctly is the test mentioned in the doc:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I am able to `clone` repos from GitHub alright to my system. However, I am not able to `push` anything (to reps where I can write). I get the following:

```
$ git push origin main         
Username for 'https://github.com': USERNAME
Password for 'https://USERNAME@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/dense-set/test_repo.git/'
```

I have tried entering my passphrase for the SSH key as well as my GitHub password, and the same `fatal` error shows.

**Question:** How can I successfully `push`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message "Support for password authentication was removed. Please use a personal access token instead."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal)

Comment: @KenY-N No, this doesn't answer my question, at least I don't see how it does. The linked post only talks about PAT's and I can't seem to put pieces there together to know what I must do.

Comment: Your local repository is still using https protocol, not ssh. Either clone again using ssh, or replace the repositoy url `git remote set-url origin <your ssh url>`