# Is it possible to git push with HTTPS protocol?

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

When I try to push to a repo I've cloned down via HTTPS protocol, it tells me to enter my username and password, then promptly errors with

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/pavelkomarov/repo.git/'
```

First of all, *why on earth* is the git client asking me for a username and password only to then tell me "Sorry, I don't accept those anymore, teehee "?

Second, is there even a way to push using HTTPS? I've only gotten `push` to work over SSH. Do you have to dig in to the git config and put some kind of key there, or is there literally just no path to do this anymore? If it's the former, it's so wildly is non-obvious how that I'm getting the impression it's the latter.

Third, why default to HTTPS when SSH is more functional? To me this is a case of [Why do we even have that lever!?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4IECphJ2RM) Is it just that they don't want all users to have to do [SSH key creation and adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git/2643584#2643584), while expecting super users to be able to figure it out? But honestly it seems like my whole team has to do these steps anyhow!

They actually boil down to not that much:

1. `cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen` followed by `cat id_rsa.pub | pbcopy`
2. navigate on the website to user settings -> SSH and GPG Keys -> add key button -> paste -> green button to complete
3. make sure you're using the SSH protocol with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user-name/repo-name.git`

This is simple enough to describe in the client's error message, or at least to put as top-line items at that web article where the error message directs users.

I've run in to this nonsense several different times over the last few years, because honestly I don't set up git on a new machine often enough to remember all these steps, and the documentation around this is overly verbose and doesn't direct you to do the minimum viable set of actions to enable `push`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal

Comment: There is a way to push via HTTP:

1. Create a Personal Access Token on the GitHub website via Profile -> settings -> developers setting -> personal access tokens, checking as many of the system access boxes as you like and choosing an appropriate expiration date.
2. Copy the key to clipboard.
3. While cloning down the repo, add the token to the url as git clone https://<username>:<githubtoken>@github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>.git, or if you've already cloned it down, set your upstream url with git remote set-url origin https://<githubtoken>@github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>.git

Comment: You can also neglect to have the token in either of the above urls and later, when prompted for username and password, give your standard username and the access token as your password, and the push goes through.

This is functionally the same as setting up SSH keys, so the steps are pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, why on earth is the git client asking me for a username and password only to then tell me "Sorry, I don't accept those anymore, teehee "?

When you cloned it, the repo's remote was initially set up as HTTPS, and you haven't changed the URL thereafter. Thus git asks for HTTPS auth details, tries to contact GitHub, and GitHub says "can't use those any more".

> Second, is there even a way to push using HTTPS? Do you have to dig in to the git config and put some kind of key there, or is there literally just no path to do this anymore? If it's the former, it's so wildly is non-obvious how that I'm getting the impression it's the latter.

The [link in the error message](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls) tells you how to do it.

> > When you `git clone`, `git fetch`, `git pull`, or `git push` to a remote repository using HTTPS URLs on the command line, Git will ask for your GitHub username and password. **When Git prompts you for your password, enter your personal access token.** Alternatively, you can use a credential helper like [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/README.md). Password-based authentication for Git has been removed in favor of more secure authentication methods. For more information, see "[Managing your personal access tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)."

(Emphasis mine.) And when you do see "Managing your personal access tokens", you will find the very clear instructions on how to create your personal access tokens, whether [finegrained](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token) or [classic](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic) (all-access) ones.

> Third, why default to HTTPS when clearly SSH is more functional

Because that was how you cloned it. (Or, you changed the URL later to be a HTTPS url, though I don't think that is very likely.) If you had cloned it with an SSH URL, you would be doing a push through SSH.

> But honestly it seems like my whole team has to do these steps anyhow! And they actually boils down to not that much

If it is not all that much, then it should be easy, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have `git config --global url.github:.insteadof https://github.com/` and `github` configured in ssh, it's that easy, a snip from `~/.ssh/config` on my desktop (physically secure so I just keep the sessions up):

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /run/user/%i/ssh-%C
ControlPersist 86400
IdentitiesOnly yes

host !aur *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

host github github.com
    HostName github.com
    user git
    ControlPersist 300
```

and from `~/.config/git/config`:

```
[url "github:"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
        insteadOf = git://github.com/
```