# Authentication error when uploading a project to GitHub

Tags: git, authentication, github

I would like to upload a directory called `pdiag` into my GitHub repository.
For this purpose, I have created a project at https://github.com/tobirolinew/pdiag.git and typed the following commands:

```
  git init
  git add .
  git commit -m "commit"
  git branch -M main
  git remote add origin https://github.com/tobirolinew/pdiag.git
  git push -u origin main
```

However, the last command returned the following error after an authentication requirement:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': tobirolinew
Password for 'https://tobirolinew@github.com': *******
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/tobirolinew/pdiag.git/'
```

I don't understand why GitHub requires authentication because I have uploaded the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` as an SSH key to GitHub. Could you please help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68784033/7976758

Answer (score 0):

You may still need to add the private key to your ssh-agent, like this...

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, I received the following error: `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

Comment: You could try `eval $(ssh-agent)` then run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Are you using Git Bash/MINGW?