# "git push" command authentication failed despite correct user name and password

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface

I am very new to tech things and I am following along with the HTML, CSS, and Javascript for Web Developers course on Coursera.
When I run 'git push' command in command line, the Github Credential Mananger appears on the screen. So I choose 'Sign in with your browser' and that opens the browser but the page says "This site can't be reach".
But in the command line, it asks User Name and Password for GitHub. I entered the correct user name and password but the authentication is failed.

[This appears when I run git push command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNvud.png)

[Error appears despite correct user name and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u3xm.png)

- I didn't change User Name or Password.
- I don't see credentials for GitHub in my windows credential manager.
- I have reinstalled git as I found in some thread that solve the problem.
- My OS is Windows 7
- git version is 2.42.0.windows.2

I appreciate if anyone could help me successfully run 'git push' command to continue the course.

Answer (score 1):

On the console you can see the following error message.

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

You will have to create a personal access token to be able to access github.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68782668/6200354) provides a detailed overview of how to do it .

Comment: If the question is already answer in another Q&A pair, it should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @knittl unfortunately I cannot flag it as duplicate, maybe not enough reputation

Comment: When it prompts you to login, you can use your username and the token as the password, or use the token as the credentails instead of username and password.