# Mirroring a repo by default

Tags: git, github

How would I allow all commits on a git repo (not Github) to be synced with an external Github repo, by default or setup when the site is provisioned? Something other than each user mirroring the remote?
The client needs a mirror of the primary repo for security scans, and doesn't want developers to have access to it. There are webhooks that could be triggered on any commit to the repo, and run such a sync-script.

Comment: Make a mirror clone? (Or don't bother, since any clone is as good as any other.)

Comment: May I ask why the client doesn't want developers to have access to the mirrored repository? I mean, they have access to the one being mirrored into it, do they not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are webhooks that could be triggered on any commit to the repo, and run such a sync-script.

Actually, since the repository is hosted on GitHub, it could set up a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) dedicated [workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions) for this mirroring.

For instance, [`actions/mirroring-repository`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/mirroring-repository)

> A GitHub Action for mirroring a repository to another repository on GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, AWS CodeCommit, etc.
>
> This will copy all commits, branches and tags.

```yaml
name: Mirroring

on: [push, delete]

jobs:
  to_gitlab:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:                                              # <-- must use actions/checkout before mirroring!
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action@v1
        with:
          target_repo_url:
            git@gitlab.com:<username>/<target_repository_name>.git
          ssh_private_key:                              # <-- use 'secrets' to pass credential information.
            ${{ secrets.GITLAB_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

---

If the source repository is not on GitHub, you can still initiate a mirroring, but this time not on every push.
You might set up an [action run on a scheduled](https://jasonet.co/posts/scheduled-actions/), which would, every 10 minutes for instance, do a `git pull`, assuming your external repository :

- can be accessed from internet
- can generate a read-access token, to be installed in your cron workflow as [a secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets)

Comment: This would be perfect @VonC, but the source repo isn't on github. The destination/mirror is. I need to maybe write a script that does this.

Comment: @Scotty The `github` tag on your question tricked me! Yes, but a webhook means installing a listener.

Comment: I removed it to avoid confusion, sorry about that.

Comment: @Scotty No the tag is relevant. You can edit the question to emphasize the "external" repository to be mirrored is not itself on GitHub. But I have edited my answer to suggest an alternative solution. The goal is to avoid webhook, since they involve a local setup on your part, as opposed to GitHub workflow, maintained and executed on GitHub itself.

Comment: OK, cool, so github actions can not only schedule it, but actually do the pull? That might work.

Comment: @Scotty Yes: example of git pull from a GitHub Action: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63041640/6309