# Using a GitHub fine-grained token with git pull over HTTPS

Tags: git, github

**Question:**

Is there a way to combine the advantages of GitHub's fine-grained PATs with the simplicity of `git pull` over HTTPS? If so, then how?

**Background**

GitHub has "classic" and "fine-grained" personal access tokens (PATs):

[image]

Go to Settings > Developer Settings to see these.

I have been using a classic PAT to run `git pull` commands over HTTPS, to pull the latest commits from GitHub:

```bash
git pull https://${token}@github.com/${owner}/${repo}.git
```

This works without prompting for a password (I keep the PAT's expiration period reasonably short).

I cannot just (naively) substitute a new fine-grained token for the classic token in my `git pull` command. It prompts me for a password. (It is treated as a user ID, I assume.)

Fine-grained PATs certainly work with the GitHub [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest). I can use the API to [get a commit](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/commits#get-a-commit) if I have the commit SHA. But that is quite low-level compared to `git pull` and I don't want to "reimplement a lot of Git functionality" ([ref](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-git-database-api)).

Fine-grained PATs are welcomed because of their ability to lock down access to specific repos and specific functions. But how (if at all) can they be used directly with `git pull` commands?

I am using Git v2.38.1 (the latest release, currently).

Comment: Note: if you are an outside contributor, f-g PATs are not supported yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally want to avoid using a token in the URL.  While this is convenient when testing things from the command line, it's not very secure, and Git is trying to make it more difficult to do this.

If you want to store this information, use a credential helper.  You can use a credential per URL in the credential helper by setting `credential.usehttppath` to true.  (You can also use something like `credential.https://github.com.usehttppath` as well.)  Then, when you're prompted for your username, specify your regular username, and specify the token for the password.

If you need to operate something from a shell script or other non-interactive use, [the Git FAQ mentions how to use a simple credential helper to read from the environment](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment).  Again, specify the token as the password, not the username.

Answer (score 21):

I used @bk2204's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74495336/12567365) and took the following steps, to move from a "token-in-the-URL" approach (bad!) to a "credentials-in-a-store" approach (better!).

Using the newer GitHub fine-grained tokens for this worked without a problem.

I wanted to document the specific steps - here they are.

---

**In GitHub:**

1. Create a new PAT: Settings > Developer Settings > Fine-grained tokens.
2. Give this token access to one repository.
3. Grant one Repository permission: Contents (read-only).

[image]

This also automatically sets the Metadata (read-only) permission, as well.

4. I did NOT need or grant any Account permissions.

---

**On my server:**

This is a headless Linux box. I do not have any 3rd party key stores integrated with Git (for example, no `libsecret`).

I chose to use the Git-provided `store`. Although this stores credentials in plaintext, it's no less secure (in my opinion) than SSH keys stored in `.ssh`. This is acceptable for my situation - and is far better than what I have been doing (placing a token directly in the URL of the `pull` command).

Specific one-time set-up commands:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

That creates the following in my global `.gitconfig` file:

```
[credential]
        helper = store
        useHttpPath = true
```

Then, in my Git repo directory, I run a simple `pull`:

```
git pull https://github.com/${owner}/${repo}.git
```

As a one-time step, I have to manually provide my user ID and the PAT at the prompts.

These credentials are stored in a new (for me) `.git-credentials` file. The format of the credentials is:

```
https://<user ID>:<fine-grained PAT>@github.com/<owner>/<repo>.git
```

I can repeat this process for more repos, each with their own PAT, as needed.

When I execute subsequent `git pull` commands, the relevant URL-specific credentials from the store are used - no command line interaction is needed.

Comment: I really like everything about your solution, except for the one-time manual having to log in. In my scenario we cannot use ssh, but need to use https and short-lived tokens. When renewing tokens, they are distributed among our build agents through an Azure Key Vault.
It would be convenient to script the generation of ~/.git-credentials before cloning, but it doesn't work although contents are binary identical with the one generated, when manually entering the username and token. Most of our agents are running Windows, so I'm looking for a PowerShell solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using same format for git pull command as classic token

```
git pull https://${token}@github.com/${owner}/${repo}.git
```

It gives a three choices to me.

#1 First (Sign in with your browser): I can login by username and password

#2 Second (Sign in with a code) : I can login by 8 digits hex code

#3 Third (Token) : I can login by fine token (PAT)

[image]

The Fine token assigned all repository or specific repositories only.
And assign [detail permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens) by PAT UI screen.

[Here](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/) is detail information about Fine grained PAT.

Answer (score -1):

Just add your username:

```bash
git pull https://${username}:${token}@github.com/${owner}/${repo}.git
```

However, as [bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74495336/19382866) stated, it is generally not recommended to have secret tokens in your URL.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. 
```remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781050/19382866, Emre Sülün.