# Use fine-grained personal access token instead of classic one

Tags: git, github, token

From [github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#about-personal-access-tokens)

> GitHub recommends that you use fine-grained personal access tokens instead of personal access tokens (classic) whenever possible

I need a simple token to access the repository (so `git clone` via https will work). I made it work with classic token but even with all possible permission fine-grained token returns
`remote: Write access to repository not granted.`

Shouldn't be code access base functionality? Is there fine-grained token replacement to read and write to the repository?

Comment: Voting to re-open because this question is about `git clone` and the linked duplicate is about `git pull`. I cannot use a fine-grained token for `git clone` - except in the way shown in a different question [GitHub clone repo with fine-grained personal access tokens (PAT)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74532852/12567365) - and that way has the disadvantage that it requires you to place the token in the URL (bad idea). I was not able to adapt the approach in this question's dupe-target to work with `git clone` in a way which protects the token.

Answer (score -1):

I can get access token via fine-grained PTA.
There are there ways to get it.

You need to give a correct write permission into PTA.
Detail information here.
[Using a GitHub fine-grained token with git pull over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493073/using-a-github-fine-grained-token-with-git-pull-over-https/74495393#74495393)

Answer (score -1):

I also start using fine-grained tokens recently I was able to clone with not issues with the following command with including `oauth2` in the url

```
git clone https://oauth2:$TOKEN@github.com/ORG/REPO.git
```