# clone GitHub repo with fine-grained token

Tags: github, github-fine-grained-tokens

With **classical** Github tokens you can clone a repo like this:

```bash
git clone https://<your-token>@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

This doesn't work with the new **fine-grained** tokens.

How do you clone a GitHub repo with the new fine-grained tokens?

Comment: Note that f-g PATs do not (currently) work for outside collaborators.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When using **fine-grained** tokens you have to prefix the token with `oauth2:` user.
like this:

```bash
git clone https://oauth2:<your-fine-grained-token>@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

*credits to Andy's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66156992/3506115)

Comment: Nice hint! FWIW, using my own username instead of `oauth2` also works.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me:
`git clone https://<your-fine-grained-token>@github.com/<ownerusername>/repo.git`

Comment: Haha, I knew I added a comment on SO how to clone repo with new tokens, still every time I have to do it, I forget how to do it. This time google redirected me to this question and you can't imagine how nice it is to see the credits in such small thing. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://${token}@github.com/${owner}/${repo}.git
```